# Saving Trace data to storage not working in Azure after publishing but working in Dev environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

This is the code I use in my WebRole OnStart method:

```html
var config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
                DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener tmp = new DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener();
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(tmp);
                //config.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 200;
                config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
                DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("Test");
```

0This is my configuration in my web.config:

```html
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
```

*Using Above Code i am able to write trace statements on azure storage table executing from my local envt. but after publishing, trace statements are not written on azure storage table.*

Answer (score 1):

This is because your OnStart method runs in WaIISHost.exe, and your web.config is configuring w3wp.exe.  This means that your OnStart code has no trace listener defined.  You can do a search for 'DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener OnStart' and find several solutions.  In general the options are:

1. Add the following code to your OnStart:

   `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());`
2. Add the `<listeners>` element to your app.config in addition to your web.config.

Comment: I Have already added listener on my OnStart() and in web.config also default listener is added also it gives problem after publishing to azure else it works fine. Anyway i have implemented it through log4net, Thanks for your Response.